# Error while loading libraries in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks, glew

I was trying to get glew working on my new Ubuntu. No problem building(seems) but during the runtime this error shows:

*error while loading shared libraries: libGlew.so.1.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

So I went to the /usr/lib and found out I have libGlew.so.**1.10**. How can i configure Code::Blocks to use the right libglew.so file? Source code seems to be irrelevant to the problem, but if it is needed I will add the source.

IDE: Code::Blocks;
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2

Edit:
I think I found the problem. The tgz package from GLEW website doesn't include the .so files (Why?).I would appreciate if somebody could share me a link to the correct version of .so files. I have been trying to find them for few hours.

Answer (score 1):

You must link your project to the library. In order to to this, right click on the project -> **build options** -> find the **Linker settings** tab -> and then click on the **Add** button and set the path to the .so file

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. I hadn't realized the version mismatch. Then removing the old version and installing the new one should work. If it is not in the ubuntu repositories, you should be able to download it.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to uninstall the tgz package.

Comment: How did you install the package? In case you did using `make install` try doing `make uninstall` in the folder of the uncompressed package. Take a look at this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439950/whats-the-opposite-of-make-install-ie-how-do-you-uninstall-a-library-in-lin)