# Is tkinter renamed in Python 3.9.0b3?

Tags: python, tkinter, error-handling, python-import, importerror

I just upgraded to python 3.9 (Earlier I had python 3.8.2)

I was working on a project where I had to use tkinter module.

Everything worked fine in Python3.8.2

### [image: pic1]

**But after upgrading to Python3.9 , I get this error** :

[image: pic2]

The error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in 
<module>
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for 
Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

So anyone knows how to fix this ?

P.S :

I have tried using

```
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

It only gives this message :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-tk is already the newest version (3.8.2-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Edit :

I found 2 `pip` installed on my system namely : `pip3` and `pip3.9` (I don't know how)

One is familiar pre existing `pip3`

When I do `pip3 list`

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ --------------------
aiohttp                  3.6.2
apturl                   0.5.2
astroid                  2.4.2
async-timeout            3.0.1
attrs                    20.2.0
autopep8                 1.5.4

#(And many more...)
```

But when I do `pip3.9 list` , I get only 2 modules installed:

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.2.3
setuptools 41.2.0
```

Comment: I think you need to upgrade system package `python3-tk` as well.

Comment: No, tkinter isn't renamed.

Comment: If you have `tcl` and `tk` development packages installed, `tkinter` will be built properly when you build Python from source. See my [result](https://imgur.com/3rUQdyx).

Comment: @acw1668 ,  and how to do that?

Comment: Do you build Python 3.9 from source?  If yes, then as I said you have to make sure `tcl-dev` and `tk-dev` packages are installed before building Python 3.9.

Comment: I would suggest you uninstall Python 3.9 and [install it with apt application manager](https://realpython.com/installing-python/#how-to-install-python-on-linux) rather than building it from the source

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does tkinter (or turtle) seem to be missing or broken? Shouldn't it be part of the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105218/why-does-tkinter-or-turtle-seem-to-be-missing-or-broken-shouldnt-it-be-part)

Answer (score 2):

Okay , Got it what was wrong (Thanks to [@acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668) ). I installed python 3.9 from the source without having dependencies (`tk-dev` and `tcl-dev`)

- **So the first thing I did was** [uninstalling Python3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439950/whats-the-opposite-of-make-install-i-e-how-do-you-uninstall-a-library-in-li)
- **Then reinstalled it using** [this method](https://www.techiediaries.com/ubuntu/install-python-3-pip-venv-ubuntu-20-04-19/) (From deadsnakes ppa)
- **Then in terminal , run** `sudo apt install python3.9-tk`
- **Now everything works fine.**

[image]

Thanks to [@Noah-J-Standerson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12982627/noah-j-standerson) for suggesting this method

Comment: I have precisely the same problem, and this didn't fix it.  When I try `sudo apt install python3.9-tk` it tells me. `Note, selecting 'python3-tk' instead of 'python3.9-tk'` and then it says `python3-tk is already the newest version (3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04)` and doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS,

Based on your python version, you need to install `python-tk`.

Example: For python 3.11, I installed `tkinter` using:

```
 brew install python-tk@3.11
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while attempting to install Python 3.11+ using `pyenv`

For Ubuntu/ WSL2:

```bash
sudo apt install tk-dev
```

did the trick