# Haskell nightmare to uninstall

Tags: macos, haskell, makefile, uninstallation

I downloaded Haskell (v. ghc-8.10.4), tarball file, and executed commands:
`configure (default /usr/local)` and
`make install`,
but the last failed on MacOS BigSur (v. 11.3.1): a sequence of "... blocked from use because it is not from an identified developer"!!
After that, the nightmare: there is no (simple) way to rollback installation cleaning up the mess below /usr/local and delete orphans and useless files of failed Haskell installation.
(The uninstall-hs doesn't work.)

Comment: Does your Makefile has an `uninstall` or similar directive ?

Comment: There is no uninstall option on Makefile

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the opposite of 'make install', i.e. how do you uninstall a library in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439950/whats-the-opposite-of-make-install-i-e-how-do-you-uninstall-a-library-in-li)

Comment: Then you want to reverse (and create your own script) the `install` starting with `make -n install`