# How to uninstall a python version which was installed from source (Ubuntu)?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, python-install

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.1 which comes whit its own python3.11 and have just installed an alternative python version (3.7.9 ) from source (I'm not able to use apt for this python version), doing the following

```
cd usr/lib
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/Python-3.7.9.tgz
sudo tar xzf Python-3.7.9.tg
cd Python-3.7.9
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

The executable (python3.7 file) was correctly installed in `/usr/local/bin` (I found this path running `which python3.7`), where also other files were installed (es. 2to3-3.7; easy_install-3.7  ; idle3.7; pip3.7 ; pydoc3.7; python3.7m-config; python3.7m; pyvenv-3.7).
A file called `python3.7` was also installed in `/usr/local/lib`.
Of course there is also a file called `python3.7.9` in `/urs/lib`.
Sincerely I don't know if other files were installed and were.

I want to delete this python installation: do I have to do it manually or there exists a simpler way?
I would add that I don't have a `make uninstall` option.
I also tried `make clean` and `make distclean` but nothing happened (the above-mentioned files are still present and `python3.7` is still working).

If there isn't an intelligent way to uninstall, is it sufficient to manually delete python3.7 related files from `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/lib`, `/urs/lib` or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: If you regularly run `make install` learn to use [`checkinstall`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14516283/7976758). See [tag:checkinstall] and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22make+install%22+uninstall

Comment: If you already ran `make install` without `checkinstall` — there is no good way to uninstall, it is sufficient to manually delete binaries and libs.

Comment: For what it's worth, the conventional meaning of `make clean` is to clean the _source_ directory by removing files which can be easily remade, and `distclean` the same without "easily" i.e. restore to the pristine sources and nothing else.

Comment: As another tangential remark, the "deadsnakes" PPA contains earlier Python versions for easy installation (and possible subsequent uninstallation) via Apt. You might also want to look at `pyenv` which lets you keep multiple Python versions installed in parallel and switch easily between them.

Comment: thank you both. I uninstalled it manually and for the future I guess I will use deadsnakes PPA  (it makes python (un)installation management easy, although checkinstall is a valid alternative)